# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:1062 Duplicate entry '2000734" for key

Tags: magento-1.7, database, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway

I am using "Sage Pay" for payment transaction in magento. But when I place order it show the following error:

> An sage pay error ocurred: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:1062 Duplicate entry '2000734" for  key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue, you need to change your `increment_last_id` of your `invoice` entity type.

By default in magento invoice entity type is **6**. Which you can find in `eav_entity_type` table.

You need to change `increment_last_id` value for your store. The `increment_last_id` is in `eav_entity_store` table. You can run following query to update your invoice `increment_last_id`. Where **X** is your new `increment_last_id` and **STORE_ID_HERE** is your store id to whom you changing invoice `increment_last_id`.

```
UPDATE eav_entity_store
       INNER JOIN eav_entity_type
         ON eav_entity_type.entity_type_id = eav_entity_store.entity_type_id
SET    eav_entity_store.increment_last_id = 'X'
WHERE  eav_entity_type.entity_type_code = 'invoice'
       AND eav_entity_store.store_id = {STORE_ID_HERE};
```

**OR**

```
UPDATE `eav_entity_store` SET `increment_last_id` = 'X' WHERE `entity_type_id` = '6';
```

**Notice that the value for increment_last_id already contains the increment_prefix. Use your entity_type increment_prefix**

For more details check here : https://www.warpconduit.net/2012/04/18/how-to-change-the-order-increment-id-and-prefix-in-magento/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Rohit, I have found that the `increment_last_id`  of `invoice` is `20004159` from the `eav_entity_store`.  So now should I directly update it to `20004160` in the `eav_entity_store` ? or is there any other table associated with it ?

Comment: @KishorePatra You can directly update it. :-)

Comment: I want to know why this number is getting duplicate. Is the code creates a problem ? or it is created by the database ?

Comment: My first guess would be there's a third party extension, core hack, or maybe even core code, that isn't handling operations with the Order objects transactionally. That, combined with an unexpected exceptions somewhere between saving an order and the internal increment number being increased, could result in orders with the same number being created. I'd check your Error and Exception logs for problems, clean those problems up, and see if the problem continues.

Otherwise you're going to need to reproduce the conditions of the errors in a test environment and debug debug debug.

Comment: @KishorePatra Is this worked for you?

Comment: I have changed it in the database..but due to some other issues, that page is still to encounter.. I will let you know about this.

Comment: That error is gone away. But another came. It is also when the payment is done, it should redirect to the order success page but instead of that it shows the following error.....SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1..Could you please suggest what steps should I follow ?

Comment: You need to check when this error firing by tracing code  when order is placed

Comment: As you know I have changed the `increment_last_id` of invoice...After that I tried to change the `increment_prefix` from 2 to 9 of a particular `store_id`. now when I place the order, the `order#`  and `invoice#` is changed from 9-digits to 10-digit. e.g 9200004375. it just prepend 9 into the number. I want to know will there be any problem in the digits ?

Comment: No problem. `increment_prefix` will be just added before your `increment_last_id`.

Comment: This did not work for me, although my error is slightly different `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
     '1000000279-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID'`